# How to checkout/update file under different name in SVN CLI?

Tags: svn, slik

In `svn` CLI (AKA `SlikSVN`), how do I check out (update) a remote file *foo.txt* under the local name *foo1.txt*?

To avoid terminology confusion, by "check out (update)", I mean simply download the file from the remote repo locally but there is already a locally changed version that I don't wish to update with the version from the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change name on `svn co`, but you can `svn cat /URL/TO/FOO > foo1.txt` (it will be unversioned unknown to SVN file)

**PS** - Better way for maintaining concurrent changes in SVN is ol' good *branching*